# Indentation not working on Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, indentation

I have a simple Custom UITableViewCell in my project, and just added an Edit action to the table.   Everything seems fine, but indentation is not working when editing, and edit Icons overlap the content.  (Not to mention the delete button)

[image: Indentation not working in custom cell]

The custom cell is created in interface builder, with the standard constraints as usual and I have already tried to ovverride the layoutSubviews method in the class, as mentioned in other places with no luck as follows;

```
(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;

self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                    indentPoints,
                                    self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.height
                                    );
}
```

I have also confirmed that the subviews are in fact within the contentView and everything seems fine in the View and Code.

Cell also has indentationLevel/Width set up programatically and autoresize masks to automatic width.

As a last resort I could create the UITableViewCell programatically, but don't think it could help.

As per recommended, I have also made sure the Constraints on the Cell content to be fixed to the superview.

[image: Fixed Margins on the left]

Also manually set de autoResizingMasks in Code with no luck

--
Edit:

I have set the Background color of the contentView to black manually, and found that it is indenting correctly on edit mode, even without overriding the "layoutSubviews".  In fact, it works better that with it.

[image]

However, as you can see, the contents are not getting indented.   Initially I tought the contents of the cell (UIImage) were not subviews of the contentView, but nslogging the subviews, show that they are.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.contentView.subviews);

"<UIImageView: 0xa477030; frame = (23 7; 31 50); autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa477090>>"
```

I'm completely lost on why this keeps happening here.  Must be some hidden constraint related to the iOS 6 new constraints stuff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indentation isn't the same as adjusting the content view when entering edit mode.

You're right, this seems simple and usually works almost straight out of the box. Typically the only things you need to change are the autoresizing masks of the components you add to the cell. Content on the left should have a fixed left margin, content on the right should have a fixed right margin.

When the cell enters editing mode the content view's size is adjusted to allow room for the editing accessories. If your content has these resizing masks, it will move along with this. Your layoutSubviews method above is quite likely undoing all this by setting the content view back to full width because you are using indentation incorrectly - though I can't be sure of that from the information in the question.

**UPDATE**

This is a issue (bug?) with constraints in UITableViewCells. You can go back to autoresizing masks by selecting the "File" tab in the storyboard / interface builder screen (if you want to use constraints elsewhere, use a standalone nib for the cell) and unchecking "Use Autolayout":

[image]

This arranges your cell content properly.

Comment: I have removed the lauoutSubview override and changed the content margins to be fixed in Interface Builder. See:  [link](http://cloud.banshai.com/image/1f202A360m2m) but still indentation is not working when entering edit mode.   Any other idea?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise you were using constraints. I haven't used them in anger yet. I'll have a think.

Comment: Looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell) has the answer you're looking for, though I can't believe it's that hard!

Comment: I've been trying everything possible to avoid doing all that, as it seems absurd, for solving such a simple problem.  I'm about to try anyway in desperation.

Comment: Agreed. It's almost worth filing a bug over.

Comment: Yea, without auto-layout and fixed margins it works out of the box.  AutoResize on the contentView.subviews changes to "autoresize = RM+BM;".  Should be a way to get this using constraints, dont you think?

Comment: and by the way, if you disable autoLayout, you will have to go through all UIViewcontroller in your storyboard and set up margins and positioning for every element in your app.  It simply gets rids of all changes you made using constraints, and put every element in default positioning.  Bad huh?

Comment: That's why I mentioned having the cell in its own nib, so you could use constraints elsewhere.

Comment: Yep.  I guess all this is some kind of unpolished corner in iOS6, and I'm too busy to keep fighting that and implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell).  Going for the independent nib cell, and auto-layout off.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow awesome, was trying to fix this all morning

Comment: @jrturton Thanks dude - it was Autolayout on my nib file that gave this issue! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these functions and work around them:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
 [super willTransitionToState:state];

 if ((state & UITableViewCellStateEditingMask) || (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)) {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
  label.alpha = 0.0;
```

// LayoutSubview code
      [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
    }

```
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
 [super didTransitionToState:state];

 if (!(state & UITableViewCellStateEditingMask) && !(state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)) {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
  label.alpha = 1.0;
// LayoutSubview code
  [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..  However fading the label manually on entering edit mode is not the right behavior in terms of usability.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Use Autolayouts" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableView edge inset to zero

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```