# Resize subviews in table view when editing using auto layout

Tags: iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have a table view with prototype cells. Currently I have only added a label to the cell. When enabling edit mode, a delete button will appear animating the cell smaller but the label doesn't reposition. This used to be no problem with autoresizing masks but now I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know how I should configure auto layout to have the label positioned inside the cell when in edit mode?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched some more and found that it is necessary to remove the horizontal spacing constraint that Interface Builder adds, as this is relative to the `UITableViewCell` and not the `contentView` and then add a constraint which is relative to the content view.

You can read more about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657891/486845) to a similar issue.