# Custom UITableViewCell Content Showing Up Outside of Grouped Style Content View

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am having this issue where my custom table view cell isn't indenting its content when being shown in a grouped style.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GameListCell";
    GameViewCell *cell = (GameViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (UIView *view in views)
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[GameViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (GameViewCell *)view;
            }
        }
    }
    Board *game = (Board *)[boardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.opponentName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game vs %@",game.opponentName];
    cell.gameDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Move: %@",game.opponentName];
    return cell;
```

Does anyone have any clue what might be going on?

I can't post an image yet, but basically the content is too far left and is outside of the rounded rectangle of the cell.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the Horizontal Space Constraint in the XIB file for the table view cell.. It has a value of "Constant" and "20". But how do I make the stuff show up in the Content View of the cell?

It looks fine in the "Plain" style, but doesn't indent for grouped style.

Thanks!

Comment: SOLUTION: I was using AutoLayout, which was forcing the constraints. I turned off auto layout, and it fixed it.

Comment: This fixes the problem but it doesn't address the bigger problem.  It's a problem if you want to use autolayout.  Is there are better solution than turning it off?

Comment: I couldn't find another solution. The issue had to do with the auto layout constraints. I'm not too familiar with those constraints and how to make them flexible.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell) helpful in explaining what's going on. Basically, XCode doesn't seem to be clever enough yet to relate the constraints to the contentView of the cell. There's a workaround where you shuffle the constraints down do the contentView in code when you load up the nib.