# Adding labels to Static Table View using Storyboard and iOS6 produces labels out of bounds when viewed in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, tableview, uistoryboard

I added a label to a cell in a static view and it looks like this:
[image: adding a Label]

And when run under iPhone simulator, it runs OK:
[image: iPhone]

But when run under iPad Simulator, the labels run out of bounds:
[image: iPad]

What I am doing wrong? Seems that the Grouped option under iPad produces larger margins but they are not taken in account when placing the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the bug in interface builder whereby constraints in cells are created against the cell, rather than its content view.

The issue is discussed at some length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell/13022753#13022753).

If you don't need Autolayout, you could turn it off, alternatively you can just use the standard cell - this has a perfectly serviceable label, there is no need to create your own.

Comment: Thanks, ended up just turning off Autolayout.