# TableViewCell "Will NOT" indent in editing mode?

Tags: uitableview, ios6, autolayout

I am working on an iOS6 build in Xcode (newest version) while in Interface Builder I have created a custom cell with just a few labels for now. I am wanting the labels to "indent" instead of getting covered up by the delete symbol on the left, and the "reorder cell rows" symbol on the right. In IB I noticed that a check box IS checked saying Indent While Editing it is also set to 10, and for some reason this still won't work? Do we have to drag a "content view" out onto the canvas as well now? I thought that was there out of the box. Also I can't get my cell height to change even though that is an option as well in IB. Could this be because of the new Auto Layout system? I know I have a cell background because i am changing the color of every other cell very slightly when I create them. I also changed the selection color to grey inside IB and this is working too.

I have searched around and everyone is asking "how to stop it from indenting" I want it to happen and its not.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell indenting doesn't work out of the box when using autolayout.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell/13022753#13022753) question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a bug in AutoLayout, where the system-generated left horizontal constraint is tied between the label and the cell's view, as opposed to the cell's `contentView`.  This may have been fixed in XCode 5.

A lot of people seem to say that turning off AutoLayout is the answer, but then you lose all the benefits of AutoLayout just to fix the indentation of one custom cell.  It's actually fixed quite easily with four lines of code (and two `IBOutlet`s, one of which you probably have already);

1. Create an `IBOutlet` for both your label and your left horizontal constraint by CTRL-dragging from each of them in Interface Builder to the header file of your `UITableViewCell` subclass, calling them "`label`" and "`leftHorizontalConstraint`" (to match the code below, or use your own names and change the code.
2. In your subclass of `UITableViewCell` overide `awakeFromNib` and add this code;

```
   // Remove the constraint that you can't delete in IB (XCode 4)
   [self removeConstraint:self.leftHorizontalConstraint];

   //Create a dictionary of variable name bindings
   NSDictionary *labelDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label);

   //Create a horizontal constraint for the label, 20 points from the left edge of its container
   NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[_label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:labelDict];

   //Add the constraint to the containerView
   [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
```

Of course, it would be a lot easier if IB generated the constraint between the label and the containerView in the first place.  This my be fixed in XCode 5, but I haven't tested it.  You should at least be able to delete the constraint by hand using XCode 5, as IB now allows you to delete system generated constraints.