# Auto Layout Error in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to debug an Auto Layout conflict in my UI.

I've set the entire UI up using IB.

The problem I'm having relates to objects inside a `UICollectionView` subclass called `FrameCell`.

The `FrameCell` has a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` that are both centered horizontally in the cell.

And the vertical constraints are like this...

```
V:|-20-[UIImageView]-50-[UILabel(==26)]-25-|
```

i.e. the height of the `UIImageView` is variable depending on the size of the cell.

However I'm getting the error...

```
( 
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x20087d00 h=--& v=--& V:[FrameCell:0x1edaf4a0(0)]>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1edafc10 UIImageView:0x1edaf960.top == FrameCell:0x1edaf4a0.top + 20>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1edafb50 FrameCell:0x1edaf4a0.bottom == UILabel:0x1edaf5c0.bottom + 25>", 
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1edafb10 V:[UIImageView:0x1edaf960]-(50)-[UILabel:0x1edaf5c0]>" 
) 

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1edafb10 V:[UIImageView:0x1edaf960]-(50)-[UILabel:0x1edaf5c0]>
```

The error is almost certainly coming from the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint but I'm not sure how to get rid of this?! WHy would it be setting the FrameCell height to 0?!

If I try to turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in the Cell I get an Internal Consistency error. I'm setting everything up using IB so I'm not sure where this AutoResizingMask is coming from?

Comment: How and where have you defined what the height of each cell in the collection view should be? It looks like somewhere this is going wrong and telling your cell to be a height of zero

Comment: I have a custom Flow Layout and in that I set the itemSize to 220x220.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if IB has the same issues when dealing with constraints within UICollectionViewCells as it does with UITableViewCells?

See @Adrians answer to this question: [contentView not indenting in iOS 6 UITableViewCell prototype cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600214/contentview-not-indenting-in-ios-6-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell)

Comment: Boom! Got it in one! Thanks. I had to remove all constraints from the FrameCell and then add my own constraints to the FrameCell.contentView. Thanks :D Very odd that I needed to do that though...

Comment: Yeah, they introduce Auto Layout to this great fanfare then fail to make IB work properly with it for UITableViewCells and UICollectionViewCells. Madness!

Answer (score 1):

Please try out this it may be help full to you 
if you want to give label size fix than use ==

```
 V:|-20-[UIImageView]-50-[UILabel(==26)]-25-|
```

Comment: Apologies, the literal layout is just a description. I'm actually using IB to add these layout constraints. It was just a way of conveying what the layout constraints are. +1 for a good spot though :D