# autolayout results differently in storyboard and run time

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I'm having a problem with the storyboard autolayout, my ViewController is of freeform size,
in the storyboard I placed 8 buttons (cookie cutter) in a row one next to the other all with the default padding as the interface builder decided.
[image]

[image]

in the story board all looks well,

But when I execute the application one button is always acting funny either it shrinks or leaks out of the view

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? 
I tried adding a trail space to the last button it didn't work

Comment: then disable the `Autolayout` feature from `Interface builder`. OR if you still want it then define each buttons Constrains in Interface builder so it wont move away away from the visible screen..

Comment: Please edit your post by adding screen shots of your layout in Xcode and your layout in the simulator, so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like your buttons are in a table view cell.  Is that so?  Xcode has a known bug regarding table view cells in xibs or storyboards with auto layout.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12600214/77567 for details.

Comment: Your layout is unsatisfiable, it seems. That happens when there are two or more layout of equal priority telling the system to create conflicting layout. In such a case, the system will break a constraint. In the top app screenshot, the system broke the width constraint on the left-most button. In the bottom app screenshot, the system broke the trailing constraint. I have a few questions: 1. Are you getting log messages about this? 2. Are all the button subviews of the container view? 3. Why don't the buttons fit when the app runs? Is the spacing wider?

Comment: @Maarten 1. not that i know of 2.the hierarchy is UITableViewController->TableView ->TableViewSection ->TableViewCell-> buttons 3.That my question, and not the size in run time and design time are exactly the same

Comment: Regarding 3: You should inspect the sizes at runtime (by using log messages or breakpoints) and compare those sizes to the sizes you have set at design time. If we know which properties are changing, we can perhaps tell *why* they're changing.